# Problema con CSS en Safari Browser

Tags: html5, css3, macos, safari

Mi archivo CSS no funciona correctamente en safari este desconfigura las posiciones otorgadas en etiquetas las cuales se suponen son compatibles, para atributos como transform, translate, rotation, y demás que no se encuentran en la lista de compatibilidad he usado **-webkit-** para darles la característica, pero a muchos otros como "width, height, position" no ha sido de utilidad. Como podría solucionar la compatibilidad de mi CSS con Safari?

añado imágenes de como se ve(safari) y como debería verse normalmente(Chrome)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vista desde Chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

etiquetas css de estilo:

```
    /*container dashboard tables*/
/*------------------------------------------*/

.container-table{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, .2);
  position: relative;
}

.container-table .header-table{
  align-content: center;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, .2);
}

.container-table .header-table h3{
  font-family:"Roboto Slab", Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: black;
}

.container-table .row-table{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row-table .img-table{
  width: auto; /* 125px*/
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.img-table img{
  width: auto;
  height: 125px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.row-table .info-table{
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-grid;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  align-content: center;
}

.row-table .info-table ul{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.row-table .info-table ul li{
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Sans-Serif;
}
```

Comment: podrias poner el HTML tambien para ver como lo construyes. es util. puedes poner tu codigo en https://jsfiddle.net/  y compartir la liga, ayudaria mucho. no hay imagenes de como se deberia de ver en chrome... :D

Comment: @PhilippeThomassigny quí está el enlace de Findle 
[https://jsfiddle.net/n0qj7ru3/3/]
En google chrome debería verse claramente los items alineados dentro del contenedor que se muestra

Comment: es un código "interesante". Si quieres usar divisiones como tablas, sinceramente, "keep it simple", usa tablas, no una simulación extraña de css contra divs para simular tablas, solo pones mucha complejidad para nada. recomendacion: usa tablas. el browser sabe perfectamente como desplegarlas sin necesidad de mil propiedades

Comment: @PhilippeThomassigny El caso, como se puede notar es que solo quiero dar forma de tabla a los objetos, pero no necesito configurarlo como una tabla `<table>`. ya que el diseño no sería el mismo... cuestiones de la empresa. Así que lo que requiero es lograr una compatibilidad con Safari, ya que no solo en esta vista se muestran los objetos de esa manera, en varias secciones de la página donde no se utilizan tablas aparecen fuera de su posición requerida.

Comment: acabo de añaidir la imagen de como se vería desde Chrome

Comment: no olvides que los elementos siempre son relativos al primer nodo superior que tiene un position relative o absolute. asegurate que los nodos superiores encapsulados tengan esta propiedad, sino la posición se calcula en base a la pagina o body etc cuanod realmente son relativos al contenedor

Comment: @PhilippeThomassigny Si, lo son... De lo contrario tendría el mismo problema con Chrome o Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Pues para olvidarte de incluir los prefijos para cada navegador deberías usar autoprefixer con algún task manager como GULP o Webpack.

Para una solución sobre tu código css, tienes una versión online que te añade todos los prefijos de forma automática:

https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: lamentablemente esto no surgió efectos aún